# General approaches to extension theorems as Caratheodory

Tags: universal-algebra, extension

I would like to know if there are some general studies about extension-like theorem, in the sense which i'm going to describe. This paragraph is not rigorous; I just would like the idea to be clear.
I will use finitary notation for operations, but they are not necessarily finitary.

Suppose you have a universal algebra $X$ of type $\mathcal{F}$ and another u.a. $X'$ of type $\mathcal{F}'$. Now take a function $T: \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}'$ on operations which preserves arities and identites of operations (call it a type-morphism). We can define a $T$-morphism $\varphi: X \to X'$ as a function such that 
$$ \varphi(f(x_1, \ldots, x_k))= T(f) ( \varphi(x_1), \ldots, \varphi(x_k) )$$
For every $x_1, \ldots, x_k \in X, \ f \in \mathcal{F}$. In measure theory, for example, one roughly prescribes disjoint union and empty set to go respectively into sum and 0.

Now take $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{F'}$ and $T: \mathcal{F'} \to \mathcal{G} $ a type morphism. Let $X$ be an algebra of type $\mathcal{F}$, $X'=\mathrm{Sg}_{\mathcal{F}'}(X)$ the $\mathcal{F}'$ algebra generated by $X$, and $Y$ an algebra of type $\mathcal{G}$. Suppose you have a (not properly) $T$-morphism $\mu: X \to Y$, in the sense that
$$ \mu( f(x_1, \ldots, x_k) ) = T(f) (\mu(x_1), \ldots, \mu(x_k) )$$
for every $f \in \mathcal{F}'$ and $x_1, \ldots, x_k \in X$ such that $f(x_1, \ldots, x_k) \in X$.

1. Which hypotesis are needed to conclude that there exists a (unique extension) $T$-morphism $\bar{\mu}: X' \to Y$ such that $ \bar{\mu}|_{X} = \mu$?
2. Can be caratheodory theorem seen as a special case of this? I can't fix the fact that one prescribes $\mu( \cup A_n ) = \sum \mu(A_n)$ (which is a type-morphism-like commutation) only for disjoint unions; but disjoint union is not an operation on $\mathcal{P}(X)$!

Thank you for your aid. If this is not the right place where to post or the question is not well posed, please 
tell me; I'm pretty new to mathoverflow and I am not confident with good practices.

Comment: Great question. I have no idea how to answer it, but I hope someone comes along and does